YouTube API to extract data from large amount of video IDs
I have a list of 2055 different video IDs (video_ids). I am trying to pull details (likes, views, etc.) from each of these videos and add them to a dictionary.
all_video_data = []

request = youtube.videos().list(
        part="snippet,contentDetails,statistics",
        id=video_ids
    )
response = request.execute()

for video in response['items']:
    data_keep = {'snippet': ['channelTitle', 'title', 'publishedAt'],
                 'statistics': ['viewCount', 'likeCount', 'commentCount'],
                 'contentDetails': ['duration']
                }
    video_data = {}
    video_data['video_id'] = video['id']

    for k in data_keep.keys():
        for v in data_keep[k]:
            video_data[v] = video[k][v]

    all_video_data.append(video_data)

The error I'm getting is because of my request block. The limit of videos per request is 50, so it makes sense when I try to do 2055. Should I be looping a request for each video id? Should I loop a request for each 50 IDs?
Tried smaller data sets of less than 50, worked. Not sure how to loop a request for every 50 and append.

For reference: you asked a very similar Stack Overflow question 79021686.

I think the best way to do it would be to send requests in batches of 50. You can do this by iterating over the list of ids in said batches in a while loop, as follows:
    while(video_ids):
        sub_ids = video_ids[0:49]
        video_ids = video_ids[50:]
        request = youtube.videos().list(
            part="snippet,contentDetails,statistics",
            id=video_ids
        )
        for video in response['items']:
        data_keep = {'snippet': ['channelTitle', 'title', 'publishedAt'],
                     'statistics': ['viewCount', 'likeCount', 'commentCount'],
                     'contentDetails': ['duration']
                    }
        video_data = {}
        video_data['video_id'] = video['id']
    
        for k in data_keep.keys():
            for v in data_keep[k]:
                video_data[v] = video[k][v]
    
        all_video_data.append(video_data)

Please let me know if this helps!!
